# transform an array of array to an array of numbers

Tags: python, numpy, repeat

I have an array of values and an array of repeated times

```
>>> x=np.arange(5)
>>> x
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> n=np.random.randint(1,3,5)
>>> n
array([2, 1, 1, 2, 2])
```

And I do

```
>>> y=np.array([np.repeat(x[i],n[i]) for i in range(5)])
>>> y
array([array([0, 0]), array([1]), array([2]), array([3, 3]), array([4, 4])], dtype=object)
```

But I want my result to be array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]).
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is simpler than you're making it [(docs)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
>>> x = np.arange(5)
>>> y = np.array([2, 1, 1, 2, 2])
>>> np.repeat(x,y)
array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4])
```